# A different way to Model a portion of this ERD

Tags: sql

I have a very simple table diagram from modeling my application.  The problem is I am second guessing my relation between Vendor and VendorOrder.  The VendorOrders table should store all vendororders in the system.  To get all orders for a certain apartment, you would just use the PK and FK relationship to gather that data.  Is there anything I should improve with the overall design?

Diagram:
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

There's three things I see that you could improve this by doing.

1. Create an **intersection table** between your Apartment and Resident tables called ApartmentResidents, where each table references the intersection table with a one to many relationship. In this ERD, it only allows for one resident to be registered to an apartment. If a resident lives in more than one apartment for the lifetime of this database, you'll need to register them as an entirely new resident.
   [Intersection table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZEBI.png)

2. In your Vendor table, instead of using a name as your primary key I would create an id instead. Using things that have a real-world value as your primary key can get messy for a number of reasons:

- If two vendors have the same name, like "Johnson's Repair", you'll need to misspell one of them for it to be a valid key.
- If you typo a vendor's name, you're also going to contain a reference to that typo in the foreign key tables (Which also might make it not show in results if you do a select query for the correct spelling).
- Placing an index on a string is less performant than if you put it on an auto incrementing integer key.

3. (Optional) I usually name my database tables pluralized, like "Apartments", or "Vendors". It makes the SQL syntax read more like a sentence inside the query. If I remember right that's also one of the things that SQL's creator was going for too with the syntax design.